# What is the meaning of this sentence: A few minutes later, she is dressed ....?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083658/synopsis)

> A few minutes later, she is dressed and Deckard, after checking the
>   lobby outside his apartment, **motions for her** to join him in the
>   elevator.

What does it mean by this highlighted sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Motions for her' means he makes a hand gesture (presumably without speaking) for her to join him.